# playing AWS Lex response audio stream using .net SoundPlayer gives error "The wave header is corrupt"

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, soundplayer

I am trying to develop a winforms application to integrating AWS lex voice service.

I am not able to play the audio received from AWS Lex bot "postContentResponse.AudioStream" in winforms application. I am using SoundPlayer to play the audio stream. Audio stream format is ".wav"

I get error "The wave header is corrupt" while playing the audio stream.

Comment: My bad, I was using SoundPlayer to play mpeg stream. Using windows media player solved the problem though I had to save the stream to physical file. SoundPlayer plays only wav format.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was using SoundPlayer to play mpeg stream. Using windows media player control solved the problem, though I had to save the stream to physical file first.

.net SoundPlayer plays only wav format.